# OFFSET FETCH CLAUSE supported in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I know OFFSET FETCH CLAUSE introduced in SQL Server 2012. I have installed SQL Server 2012 and I created a database with the compatibility level (SQL Server 2008).

Then I tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
ORDER BY name 
      OFFSET 10 ROWS
      FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

The above query returns 20 rows. How does `OFFSET FETCH CLAUSE` work in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I have tried in SQLfiddle as well by choosing `SQL SERVER 2008` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3799/1 and it works there as well.

I browsed in internet about it but I didn't find any solution as of now. Is that behaving because of 2012 Instance? Is there a way to make 2012 instance database to execute only SQL Server 2008 queries?(through any other settings if any)

Comment: @GSerg : So i need to set the compatibility to SQL Server 2000(80). So that only SQL Server 2008 version related queries will execute.Am i rite?

Comment: SQL Server **2012** no longer supports the compatibility level 80 (SQL Server 2000)

Comment: No you are not rite @knkarthick24. The point of the linked question is that `Compatibility level provides only partial backward compatibility` and `New functionality might work under older compatibility levels`.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for mentioning the above point. Thanks GSerg for the detailed explanation on my clarification. Is there a way to make 2012 instance database to execute only SQL Server 2008 queries?(through any  other settings)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a backup database taken from SQL Server 2008 R2, but your current server is SQL Server 2012.

With compatibility to 2008, the features available in 2012 are available for your database as well.

Note: The database backup don't have backward compatibility i.e., a database backup taken in SQL Server 2012 cannot be restored in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: No. I am not using any backup. I created one new database with Compatibility level set to SQL Server 2008. IF i set the compatibility to certain version it should support only that specific version queries. am i rite?